# vue-cookies get value return Object instead of actual value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cookies

I am using vue-cookies npm package in my vue project. I have no problem install the package, initialize it in the project and setting the cookie. However, when I tried to retrieve the value stored in the cookie by key, instead of showing me the value I stored, it showed me `[object Object]`, and I am not sure what went wrong:
Here is my code:

```
this.cart.push({
  productID: this.product._id,
  product: {
    productName: this.product.productName,
    thumbnail: this.product.productMedia[0].imagePath,
    option: 'Digital Download'
  },
  unitPrice: this.product.price.listingPrice,
  quantity: 1
})
console.log(this.cart)
this.$cookies.set('cart', this.cart, 60 * 60 * 24)
console.log(this.$cookies.isKey('cart'))
console.log(this.$cookies.get('cart'))
```

I made sure `this.cart` is not empty, `$this.$cookies.isKey('cart)` returned `true`, however, `$cookies.get()` method returned `[object Object]`instead of the cart value I stored. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting the JSON object in the cookie. You can set the key value as JSON string instead of JSON object.

```
this.$cookies.set('cart', JSON.stringify(this.cart), 60 * 60 * 24)
```

While getting then you can access by parsing the JSON string into an object.

```
JSON.parse(this.$cookies.get('cart'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the value in the console try doing

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.$cookies.get('cart')))
```

The object in question may be nested which is why it won't print.